# Inaccessible field error

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Sometimes when I write a Class and then test it, I get the error in the picture at the bottom, and when I try to debug it the editor shows me that the attributes I want to access are "inaccessible values" (initializing them in the constructor works surprisingly).

The last time I got this problem I simply fixed it by copying the code into a new Unit and deleting the old one, so I assumed it had something to do with the precompiled .dcu files. But unfortunately that tricky solution doen´t work with this class, did I do something wrong or is this caused by Delphi 7 being outdated (I´m working on Win8)?

```
unit UVector;

interface

uses

    SysUtils, Types;

type

    Vector2f = class

        private

           x : extended;
           y : extended;

        public

            function getX() : extended;
            function getY() : extended;
            constructor create(x,y : extended);
            procedure add(v : Vector2f);


        end;


implementation

constructor Vector2f.create(x,y : extended); // works!
begin
    self.x := x;
    self.y := y;
end;

procedure Vector2f.add(v : Vector2f);
begin
    //inc(x, v.getX());     // compiler error : left side cannot be assigned to
    //inc(y, v.gety());     // compiler error : left side cannot be assigned to
    self.x := self.x + v.getX(); //inaccessible value (at runtime) for x and getX()
    self.y := self.y + v.getY(); //inaccessible value (at runtime) for y and getY()
end;

function Vector2f.getX() : extended;
begin
    result := x;
end;

function Vector2f.getY() : extended;
begin
    result := y;
end;


end.
```

[image: error]

Comment: It would help to see how you are using this class, are you sure that the value passes in `procedure Vector2f.add(v : Vector2f);` has been assigned and that the class itself has been constructed before its use? The `inaccessible value` at run time may be a red herring as you can get this if you do not have a break point on that line of code as the compiler sometimes optimizes it away.

Comment: yes to both, and I have already recompiled it without compiler optimizations, doen´t change anything unfortunately :(

Comment: Nothing in the code you posted would generate that exception except the use of `v` in `Add` (if `v` hasn't been created. You need to also post the code that's creating the instances of your class and using them, because the problem isn't here.

Comment: Read of address 00000008 means that you're reading a variable at an offset of 8 bytes from a nil pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, on why `Inc` does not work, from the [help on the `Inc` routine](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/System_Inc@.html):

> Increments an ordinal value by one or N. ... X is a variable of an ordinal type (including Int64)...

`Extended` is not an ordinal value type but a real value type.

---

Secondly, on why you are getting an access violation; an AV, especially when the read address approaches zero, chances are very likely that you are accessing an unassigned object variable, which also results in the *Inaccessible value* debugger hint.

This test code works:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  V1: Vector2f;
  V2: Vector2f;
begin
  V1 := Vector2f.create(123.45, 234.56);
  V2 := Vector2f.create(123.45, 234.56);
  try
    V1.add(V2);
    Caption := FloatToStr(V1.getX);  // Outputs 246.9
  finally
    V2.Free;
    V1.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Thus, one of the following causes is at hand:

- you haven't created the object you work on,
- you haven't created the object you are passing.